# Port Error While Connect MSSQL with Android Device?

Tags: android, sql-server, windows, networking, network-programming

I developing a software and its will work in Android. Also, for my Android App, I'm developing Windows App too and they all need to connect MSSQL Server.

I configure to SQL Server and I can connect SQL Server with Windows App and Android Emulator. But I can't connect my SQL Server with real Android Device. App throwing that error;

> "Network error IOException: failed to connect to /'My Computer Static IP' (port
>   1433): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)"

Already I'm setup to 1433 port for my SQL Server, but I can't connect. Please Help me...

Why I can connect with Emulator but I can't connect with Real Android Device?

Thanks for answer. Have a good day.

Comment: 1-Where are you telling the app the static IP address were SQLServer is running? 2-What emulator are you using?

Comment: 1-) SQL Server Running in virtual machina. Virtual Machian OS is Win7. I'm make static ip this virtual machine and configure SQL Server Configuration for this IP and 1433 port.    2-) I'm using Android Studio. I don't understand what you mean with that question. Could I send Emulator Configuration? Emulator API Level 22 and my real device API level 16.

Comment: are you using bridged network in the VM of SQL Server or host only or NAT or internal? If it works with the emulator running in same PC and doesn't work with phone, it's very possible you have a problem with IP address or Firewall.

Comment: Mr. @rodolk I'm using Bridged network in my VMware. In VMware, I'm turn off the firewall and get same error.